# Install latest cmake binary and accept licence automatically

Tags: 16.04, c++, cmake

I'm trying to install the latest binary version of cmake, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, automatically (via ansible).

I have so far done:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.10/cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64.sh
sudo ./cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

However, this then brings up the licensing agreements.

Is there any way to add a prefix, or something which automatically accepts the agreements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you run the installer with `--help` you should find that it has a `--skip-license` command line option:

```
$ ./cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64.sh --help
Usage: ./cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64.sh [options]
Options: [defaults in brackets after descriptions]
  --help            print this message
  --version         print cmake installer version
  --prefix=dir      directory in which to install
  --include-subdir  include the cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64 subdirectory
  --exclude-subdir  exclude the cmake-3.10.0-rc4-Linux-x86_64 subdirectory
  --skip-license    accept license
```